windows 11 taskbar wasted space
I really dislike that Microsoft will force me to upgrade Win10 to Win11, but I already have it on my work laptop. I tried to make it look as I like it - for example disable the silly grouping of app icons and ENABLE the window titles. It's fine, however what is this weird empty space in the tray zone? It is taking up space which could be used by another app tile!

Weirdly if I logout and login again this seems to be fixed and the space disappears, but later probably after hibernating and waking up the laptop it reverts to this state. Is this normal or mistake that I can fix somehow?

It’s trivial to prevent the upgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 11. Why don’t you just use the group policy to prevent the upgrade?

as I said this is a work laptop so I got what I got. And on the other hand don't you know that Windows 10 will eventually stop being supported? That's not very good practice to hold onto unsupported OS.

I never said it was a good idea. I just said it was possible so saying your forced to upgrade to Windows 11 is  very complicated statement. Ultimately Windows 11 isn’t Windows 10 and it does look different and will continue to diverge from it’s predecessor.  Does this weird spacing happen when you boot into a minimal configuration?

I didn't try booting into minimal configuration, but I really think it would be much easier if other people just confirmed to me if this is normal behavior and happens to them as well if they fill up the taskbar with open windows. Or not and it's just me and specifically my laptop. Wouldn't that be more effective? :)

I have never seen it I have multiple Windows 11 VMs and various physical machines running different builds of Windows 11 (21H2, 22H2, and 23H2)

As this is a work computer we do not know what policies or software or restrictions your employer has applied to this computer. You should begin by speaking with your designated IT staff. That said, for an issue like this I would begin by checking for and installing any available updates to firmware, drivers, and OS patches.

My company forced an update to Windows 11 and this was the first bug (among many others) that I've noticed. This question was closed because of lack of clarity but it's clear to me it's a well know bug when you have multiple windows open. I can even fix it by closing enough windows for the wasted taskbar space to be reclaimed. Maybe it's a result of some group policies being applied, as this is also a work computer like @Vitas

I've seen this issue too and it (among many, many other things in W11) drives me nuts.
